# How to fix pip permissions after accidental `sudo pip install` usage

Tags: python, pip

I know I shouldn't use `sudo pip3 install`, but while following a Django tutorial, I inadvertently did. Prior to the that command, pip3 defaulted to `--user`. Afterwards, I have to explicitly type it out. How do I revert back to having `--user` by default?

Comment: The first question is to know what pip3 is being used. The default setting (to use `--user` or not) might have changed in an update of pip. The [current version of pip](http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs) does not have `--user` by default but you can change that via a local [configuration file](http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file)